# Not able to scrape the all the reviews

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape this [website](https://www.capterra.com/p/134048/HiMama-Preschool-Child-Care-App/#reviews) and trying to get the reviews but I am facing an issue,

- The page loads only 50 reviews.
- To load more you have to click "Show More Reviews" and I don't know how to get all the data as there is no page link, also "Show more Reviews" doesn't have a URL to explore, the address remains the same.

> url =
>   "https://www.capterra.com/p/134048/HiMama-Preschool-Child-Care-App/#reviews"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
a = []

url = requests.get(url)
html = url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

table = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"review-comments"})
#print(table)
for x in table:
    a.append(x.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.to_csv("review.csv", sep='\t')
```

I know this is not pretty code but I am just trying to get the review text first.
kindly help. As I am little new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the website, the "Show more reviews" button makes an ajax call and returns the additional info, all you have to do is find it's link and send a get request to it (which I've done with some simple regex):

```py
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/74.0.3729.169 Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
}
url = "https://www.capterra.com/p/134048/HiMama-Preschool-Child-Care-App/#reviews"
Data = []
#Each page equivalant to 50 comments:
MaximumCommentPages = 3 

with requests.Session() as session:
    info = session.get(url)
    #Get product ID, needed for getting more comments
    productID = re.search(r'"product_id":(\w*)', info.text).group(1)
    #Extract info from main data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(info.content, "html.parser")
    table = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"review-comments"})
    for x in table:
        Data.append(x)
    #Number of pages to get:
    #Get additional data:
    params = {
        "page": "",
        "product_id": productID
    }
    while(MaximumCommentPages > 1): # number 1 because one of them was the main page data which we already extracted!
        MaximumCommentPages -= 1
        params["page"] = str(MaximumCommentPages)
        additionalInfo = session.get("https://www.capterra.com/gdm_reviews", params=params)
        print(additionalInfo.url)
        #print(additionalInfo.text)
        #Extract info for additional info:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(additionalInfo.content, "html.parser")
        table = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"review-comments"})
        for x in table:
            Data.append(x)

#Extract data the old fashioned way:
counter = 1
with open('review.csv', 'w') as f:
    for one in Data:
        f.write(str(counter))
        f.write(one.text)
        f.write('\n')
        counter += 1
```

Notice how I'm using a session to preserve cookies for the ajax call.

Edit 1: You can reload the webpage multiple times and call the ajax again to get even more data.

Edit 2: Save data using your own method.

Edit 3: Changed some stuff, now gets any number of pages for you, saves to file with good' ol open()

Comment: @AmitGupta sure, this should get top 100 comments

Comment: That is the issue, the link you are saying, I think that can be get from the html element but I am able to find any such link. So can you please complete and bring it in as a dataframe. I don't see anything printing

Comment: The link is at the end of the page source, its something like ```<a href="#" class="no-underline  show-more-reviews" data-url='/gdm_reviews?page=1&amp;product_id=134048' data-target="#capterra-reviews .reviews-list">
      <i class="ss-thumbnails  icon-lead"></i>Show more reviews
    </a>```

Comment: Yes, I see this part but when you click on "Show More Reviews" everything remains the same except the page number in the data-url, and the address also the remains same. so I am not able to understand to what new url should update.

Comment: @AmitGupta The new url just fetches the data from the website and some javascript inserts them into the webpage source; Therefore the webpage doesn't change only it's contents.

Comment: @AmitGupta There ya go, hope this helps. The rest (organizing data) i suggest you try to do yourself